# onClick event handler for button is not executed from a list of buttons

Tags: android

I have a list of buttons and I am loading them in list like this:

```
positionButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.positionBtn0));
positionButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.positionBtn1));
positionButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.positionBtn2));
```

I am adding event handlers like this:

```
Button.OnClickListener currentPositionListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Current position selected");
            setSelectedPositionButton((Button) view);
        }
    };


for (Button positionButton: positionButtons) {
        positionButton.setOnClickListener(currentPositionListener);
}
```

The event handlers never get executed (no error messages though) and I need to have a separate variable for each button for the event handler to be executed:

```
positionButton0.setOnClickListener(currentPositionListener);
```

Why is this happening? Is there a workaround so that I can just add buttons to a list and work from there instead of going through the step of declaring separate variables?

**UPDATE:**

Please reply to the actual question and don't treat it as troubleshooting.  If in your opinion and experience this should be working you could just add a comment or reply with an actual working example. I am not trying to debug my code, just trying to get more insight.

Comment: Try `View.OnClickListener currentPositionListener = new View.OnClickListener() {.....};` Instead of `Button.OnclickListener`

Comment: can you share full source code. also try to put the Toast or use debug inside  `onClick` method for make sure this method is not called (because sometime logcat not display)

Comment: @AkshayBhat nope. I already tried this.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh In your opinion should this be working? I can't share source  code right now. I had also used Toast and it didn't work (although not displayed in the code sample).

Comment: implement OnClickListener in activity and use `button.setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: @atas76 I think it will be working. just need to share your onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this:

```
for (Button positionButton: positionButtons) {
    positionButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            // write your code...
        }
    });
}
```